# html CSS Table Scroll from the middle of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 20 Columns in my **HTML Table**. I will be having hundreds of records on my table. I have kept a horizontal scroll but my problem is When I am viewing the records on middle Part of the table and I want to scroll horizontally, I want to go to the bottom of the table.

> **I need an option to scroll from the middle of the table**

```
<div style="width: 1100px;overflow-x: auto;">
<table >
<thead>
<td>Col-1</td>......<th>col-20</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php echo "dynamic Records"; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, put some code in your question to show what have you done so far.

Comment: Updated my sample table

Comment: @Brindha put the `<table>` within a `<div>` with `overflow:auto;` and give width and height to the `<div>` as per design requirement.

Comment: @NikhilKinkar Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to view the table within the `<div>`, this `<div>` will be the viewport, that way you can view the table of any size, and can scroll vertically and horizontally to access complete table. try this code, it should work as you expected.

```css
.parent {
  /* width: 500px; */
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 1100px;
  border: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <table class='child'>
    <thead>
      <td>Col-1</td>
      <th>col-20</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col-1 Data</td>
        <td>col-2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <?php echo "dynamic Records"; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```